# Print header as a first field - bash

Tags: bash, loops, text

I'm struggling with the following task.
I have file in the form:

```
header
abc def
ghi jkl
header2
mno pqr
stu wvx
...
```

I'd like this form:

```
header abc def
header ghi jkl
header2 mno pqr
header2 stu wvx
...
```

I know there must be plethora of solutions using any programming language, but I couldn't find anything what could help me. I'd appreciate suggestion, preferably using `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: What are all those characters before `header`? `>` and `\`, should they be removed? or present actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given input with headers as `header`, `header2`, the `Awk` logic can be pretty simple,

```
awk '/header/{h=$0; next} {$0=(h FS $0)}1' file
```

produces the output as you need. But if your *actual* header name varies but follows the pattern of a name followed by `1`,`2` and subsequently, the above code should work if you replace `header` in the above example with your actual header line.

---

As suggested by [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) over in comments, another way to check for the header is check for single fields in a line using the `NF==1` condition as

```
awk 'NF==1{h=$0; next} {$0=(h FS $0)}1' file
```

Comment: You could check if `NF==1` instead of regex to make it work with any header(assuming they are all one word/field)

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific `header` are just example text. In my file they are different strings, starting with `>` so regex helps. Eventually the code become `awk '/>/{h=$0; next} {$0=(h FS $0)}1' x6 > xx2` . Thanks!

Comment: @MaciejJończyk: Can you give actual examples of those headers. This is where you should provide real examples of your sample lines. (or) try the second `Awk` answer which I provided, it should work for your case